How to overwrite GeoJSON file data from the front end of a web app?
So I currently have a web app running on GitHub Pages that features an interactive map (created using Mapbox GL JS)--the data for which is stored using two different GeoJSON files. I have an upload feature where users can upload a new csv file with map data & I've successfully implemented the logic that converts that csv data into the GeoJSON format I need.
Now, I'm struggling to overwrite the existing GeoJSON files with the newly added data from the user after they upload. What is the best way to do this?
To recap, basically:

step 1. user uploads csv file (works)
step 2. csv file data gets converted to GeoJSON data (works)
step 3. new GeoJSON data should overwrite old GeoJSON file data & then page refreshes so map can reflect changes (I am lost here.)

// map.js file
// Event listeners for upload buttons
document.getElementById('apply-master-sites-upload').addEventListener('click', function () {
    convertCSVtoGeoJSON('master-sites-upload', function (err, geojson) { 
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Successfully converted CSV to GeoJSON:', geojson); // this works!
            // make a POST request to the server
            fetch('/upload-master-sites', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ geojson: geojson })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }
    });
});
document.getElementById('apply-app-deployment-upload').addEventListener('click', function () {
    convertCSVtoGeoJSON('app-deployment-upload', function (err, geojson) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Successfully converted CSV to GeoJSON:', geojson); // this works!
            // make a POST request to the server
            fetch('/upload-app-deployment', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ geojson: geojson })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }
    });
});

// server.js file
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/upload-master-sites', (req, res) => {
    const geojson = req.body.geojson;

    fs.writeFileSync('./data/master_site_listing.geojson', JSON.stringify(geojson));

    res.json({ message: 'Master sites data uploaded successfully.' });
});

app.post('/upload-app-deployment', (req, res) => {
    const geojson = req.body.geojson;

    fs.writeFileSync('./data/app_deployment.geojson', JSON.stringify(geojson));

    res.json({ message: 'App deployment data uploaded successfully.' });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

I have been trying to figure out a server-side solution but I keep getting a 405 Method Not Allowed error with no further details as to what's going on.
What I wanted was for the GeoJSON files in my project's repository to update for all future viewers & for the map's points to change and reflect the contents of the newly entered dataset.

Or can I only use a localStorage solution for security reasons?

I'm not sure what exactly you have in mind. But my suggestion is to clearly explain one core problem with one goal, and add links to your external web app. The JavaScript tag on SO has many pro developers that they will answer your questions one by one. For example, you could ignore security at this point, so that you'd get your app up and running. Step by step. One problem at the time (in your question as well).

Note that you can break your problem into multiple questions. It'd be easier to understand your problem (e.g., you can add a question about the 405 error).
